# Only log certain metrics with spacy.MLflowLogger.v2

Tags: spacy, mlflow, spacy-3

I am using the spacy.MLflowLogger.v2 logger in spaCy while training a textcat model. Here's how  my logger config looks like:

```
[training.logger]
@loggers = "spacy.MLflowLogger.v2"
experiment_id = "1"
run_name = "somemetrics"
nested = False
remove_config_values = ["paths.train", "paths.dev", "corpora.train.path", "corpora.dev.path"]
```

The logging works well, however, it is logging metrics I do not plan to track and I would therefore only like to track a couple of metrics e.g. `cats_macro_f` and `cats_micro_f`.

I have tried using the `log_custom_stats  = ["cats_micro_f"]` option, however, it still logs all the other metrics. In fact, when looking at the logger source code, I can see the following function:
def log_step(info: Optional[Dict[str, Any]]):
_log_step_mlflow(mlflow, info)
_log_custom_stats(mlflow, info, match_stat)

Which will anyway log all metrics in `_log_step_mlflow` before using the regular expressions listed in `log_custom_stats`.

Could anyone please explain how I prevent `spacy.MLflowLogger.v2` from logging all metrics and only log specific metrics?